# $3$ states and $3$ students

Tags: combinatorics

Please provide an approach for the following problem.

> There are $3$ states and $3$ students representing each state. In how many ways can $5$ students be chosen such that at least one student is chosen from each state?

Comment: I don't believe the problem is complete. What is the total number of students in the class?

Comment: @heather It's $9$. Three people representing each of three states.

Comment: Brute forcing in Haskell: `length $ filter (\(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8,x9)->(x1+x2+x3>=1) && (x4+x5+x6>=1) && (x7+x8+x9>=1) && (x1+x2+x3+x4+x5+x6+x7+x8+x9==5)) [ (x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8,x9) | x1 <- [0,1], x2 <- [0,1], x3 <- [0,1], x4 <- [0,1], x5 <- [0,1], x6 <- [0,1], x7 <- [0,1], x8 <- [0,1], x9 <- [0,1] ]` produces `108`

Answer (score 2):

Note that there are $\binom{9}{5}$ ways to choose the students without the condition. Now to calculate the "bad" combinations we count the ways to choose $5$ students from just $2$ countries and there are $3 \cdot \binom{6}{5}$ ways to do that. Therefore the number you're after is:

$$\binom{9}{5} - 3 \cdot \binom{6}{5}$$